# How to Extract Where Part of an Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm struggling to understand how expressions work in C# LINQ queries.

I have an entity `Assignment` which has `Persisted` and `SessionId` properties I always use to filter using this expression:

```
public static Expression<Func<Assignment, bool>> HasCorrectPersisted(int[]? sessions)
{
    return e => e.Persisted && sessions!= null && !sessions.Contains(e.SessionId ?? 0) || !e.Persisted && (sessions== null  ||  e.SessionId != null && sessions.Contains(e.SessionId.Value));
}
```

(The expression doesn't really matter, only that it's complex.)

So anytime I do something with the `Assignment`s, I'll use `dbContext.Assignments.Where(HasCorrectPersisted(sessions))`. So far so good.

Now a list of these entities belongs to a entity `Parent`, and I'm struggling to assign the same filter to these.

I tried:

```
dbContext.Parents.Include(p => p.Assignments.Where(HasCorrectPersisted(sessions)));
```

Which leads to this compiler error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'Where(Expression<Func<Assignment,bool>>)', candidates are: 
IEnumerable<Assignment> Where<Assignment>(this IEnumerable<Assignment>, Func<Assignment,bool>) (in class Enumerable) 
IEnumerable<Assignment> Where<Assignment>(this IEnumerable<Assignment>, Func<Assignment,int,bool>) (in class Enumerable)
```

This is pretty clear, no `Expression` should be used, so I replaced it with (note the `Compile()`):

```
dbContext.Parents.Include(p => p.Assignments.Where(HasCorrectPersisted(sessions).Compile()));
```

Which leads to this exception, which kinda makes it sound like `Expression` was the correct parameter type after all:

```
ArgumentException : Expression of type 'Func`2[Assignment,Boolean]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'Expression`1[Func`2[Assignment,Boolean]]' of method 'IQueryable`1[Assignment] Where[AssignmentViewEntity](IQueryable`1[Assignment], Expression`1[Func`2[Assignment,Boolean]])' (Parameter 'arg1')
```

So I started casting and forcing the expression:

```
dbContext.Parents.Include(p => ((IQueryable<Assignment>)p.Assignments)..Where(HasCorrectPersisted(sessions)));
```

Which leads to:

```
The expression 'Convert(d.Assignments, IQueryable`1).Where(e => (False OrElse (Not(e.Persisted) AndAlso True)))' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.
```

So this means... that the expression is just to complex for the include?

If I copy the logic from the method `HasCorrectPersisted()` into the `Where()` it works, so it's not the complexity per se.

Is there any way to use such a complex expression in the include without copying it?

Comment: Yeah, I think you're going too complex for Include. It may even need to a be memberaccess expression only, just with your navigation properties. You may be able to get `dbContext.Parents.Include(x => x.Assignments).Where(...)`, where the where clause can check if any assignments have the correct sessions?

Comment: Yeah, re-reading, that last error message alludes to this. Too complex, must just reference navigation properties, see the link for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bit of a curious one, but I was able to get the query to accept the `Expression<Func<>>`, you need to use `AsQueryable` with the child collection rather than the casting:

```
.Include(p => (p.Assignments.AsQueryable().Where(HasCorrectPersisted(...)))
```

There does seem to be a few issues with your expression. Firstly you appear to be ORing several conditions, but without parenthesis the order of operations would likely be returning results you don't expect:

At a guess I'd suspect it should be something like:

```
public static Expression<Func<Assignment, bool>> HasCorrectPersisted(int[]? sessions)
{
    return e => (e.Persisted && sessions!= null && !sessions.Contains(e.SessionId ?? 0)) 
        || (!e.Persisted && (sessions == null  ||  e.SessionId != null && sessions.Contains(e.SessionId.Value)));
}
```

From that I'd probably simplify it so that the simplified expression is passed based on whether the array contained values:

```
public static Expression<Func<Assignment, bool>> HasCorrectPersisted(int[]? sessions)
{
    if (sessions != null)
        return e => (e.Persisted && !sessions.Contains(e.SessionId ?? 0)) || sessions.Contains(e.SessionId);
    else 
        return e => !e.Persisted;
}
```

The iffy bit there is the `...Contains(e.SessionId ?? 0)` and whether that will translate down to SQL reliably. You may need to handle that more explicitly, but this should hopefully be nudging the solution closer to working.. :)

Comment: Even with the `AsQueryable()` I get the "The expression is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access" error message. It works if I just copy the expression into the `Where()`, so the complexity of the expression doesn't seem to be the problem - extracting it into its own method is.

Comment: What version of EF? did you try simplifying the expression like the 2nd example? I had tried a couple of examples /w EF Core 6 and it was fine with the `Expression<Func<>>` method in the `Include(x => x.y.AsQueryable().Where())`. Filtering Includes is not supported in EF6 and not sure which EF Core versions fully support it.

Comment: It does work now. Dunno what I did wrong the first try. Thanks!